# How to search all links from a specific page?

Tags: google-search

How do I search for `site:X keywords` with X is all the links you get from a specific Y page? I can't come up any solution.

Comment: I expect you could get all of the sites from a page with some tool then add that list to a Google Custom Search Engine, then do your keyword search from there.

Answer (score 0):

[Firefox Extension](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/firelinkreport-research-on-page-links-firefox/17714/), From experience you can <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
[Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-klipper-extract-all/fahollcgofmpnehocdgofnhkkchiekoo) <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in the file it saves
[A brokenish old tool on the web](http://www.iwebtool.com/link_extractor) (when the servers are under load it won't work)